# android Sqlite connectivity

Tags: android, sqlite, connectivity

i am devloping a game application in android using sqlite connectivity.. all thing is going good.. but now i want to do like that, so only past 20 data remain in my database.. that mean at every insert data statment i want to delete last data remaining last assending 20 data

Comment: constantly deleting entries might be a costly operation. Instead use creation times in your rows, and use that to query the db for the last 20 entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be done using sql query. First retrieve total number of records available in table.
then use if-else condition.

if number of records>20

then {
           delete a record according to condition;

insert new record in table.

}

else
      insert new record in table.